# multiple iFrame embedding

Tags: seo, html, iframe

I've got a single page on my blog for the pdf publications embedded from sites like Issuu.com

Each of these publications is embedded using the iFrame.

These are slowly piling up and I will very soon end up with 20 iFrames embedded 
into one single page.

I am quite worried about SEO in this case. Does putting several iFrames into one single page affect SEO ??

Comment: Hi @John Conde, firstly the question is not a duplicate of my question. The question is asking if we still need to avoid using iframes in general and if that is a good practice ? I know that there is no problem using iframes, but my question is if there is a problem using 20 iframes in a single page.

Comment: And also secondly, the answered question you pointed to was last answered in 2010. As google and search engines are constantly developing, I do believe that many things may also have changed in terms of using iFrames.